# Create an array of colors (about 100) in JavaScript, but the colors must be quite distinct

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of colors in javascript, for that, I used the js file rainbowvis.js [here](https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS), I have 100 colors, but they are not really distinct.

I should be able to see the difference because I will use this table to a chart.

Is it possible with rainbowvis.js or is there an other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate 100 colors (each color from 1 to 1000000 - change it if you need other range):

```
var colors = [];
while (colors.length < 100) {
    do {
        var color = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
    } while (colors.indexOf(color) >= 0);
    colors.push("#" + ("000000" + color.toString(16)).slice(-6));
}
console.log(colors);
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cr8v/)

Answer (score 4):

Use [distinct-colors](https://github.com/internalfx/distinct-colors).

It generates a palette of *visually* distinct colors.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a faster alternative, we could employ a random number generator and use the 'rgb()' color model instead

```
var COLORS = [];
while (COLORS.length < 100) {
    COLORS.push(`rgb(${rand(0, 255)}, ${rand(0, 255)}, ${rand(0, 255)})`);
}

// random number generator
function rand(frm, to) {
    return ~~(Math.random() * (to - frm)) + frm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RGB colors.

```js
var colors=[], tds='';
for( var r=0; r<256; r+=25 ){
    for( var g=0; g<256; g+=25 ){
        for( var b=0; b<256; b+=25 ){
            var c="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
            tds+="<p style='display:inline-block;margin:0;width:32px;height:32px;background:"+c+"'></p>";
            colors.push(c);
        }        
    }
} 
document.body.innerHTML=tds;
```